# Change key in js associative array

Tags: javascript

If I have:

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray['hello'] = value;
```

How can I change the key 'hello' to something else?

Something like this would work.

```
var from = 'hello',
    to   = 'world',
    i, value = myArray[from];

for( i in myArray )
  if( i == from ) myArray.splice( i, 1 );

myArray[to] = value;
```

But is there a native function or a better way to do it?

**edit:**

Due to the lack of associative arrays in js, what I want to do modify the property name of an object as efficiently as possible.

Comment: The "splice()" method won't work for named properties.  It's an Array method and as such it only operates on the integer-indexed properties of the object.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In JavaScript there is no such thing as associative Array. Objects can be used  instead:

```
var myHash = new Object();
```

or

```
var myHash = {};
```

replace can be done like this:

```
myHash["from"] = "value";
myHash["to"] = myHash["from"];
delete myHash["from"];
```

but the preferred way to write it:

```
myHash.from = "value";
myHash.to = myHash.from;
delete myHash.from;
```

Comment: The problem with delete is that it doesn't really delete, it just sets the value to undefined.

Comment: That should not be true according to the documentation: http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.3/reference/ops.html#1045837

Comment: I think in arrays that is true, so I'm sorry I mentioned associative array, but I am actually working with objects. Its the PHP in me. So does that mean my approach is the way to go?

Comment: If you want to understand a lot more about delete in javascript, this is a pretty useful article about it: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really "change" the property name, but you can always assign a property value to a new name, and then delete the original one.

```
myArray['world'] = myArray.hello;
delete myArray.hello;
```

Also, you're working with an Array instance but using it as a simple object; everything you're doing would work just as well with:

```
var myArray = {};
```

The "splice()" you're attempting in the code posted won't work, because it's only for the actual integer-indexed array properties, and not the named properties.

That "delete" doesn't really delete a property really doesn't matter. The "undefined" value is what you get when you check an object for a property and there's no such property.